# How to use *ngIf and conditional required together in angular?

Tags: angular

```
<div class="p-field-checkbox">
    <p-checkbox formControlName="passwordUpdate" binary="false" name="passwordUpdate" inputId="passwordUpdate"></p-checkbox>
    <label for="passwordUpdate">Update Password</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group" *ngIf="form.get('passwordUpdate').value">
    <label class="required" for="password">Password</label>
    <input formControlName="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="input input-m" [required]="form.get('passwordUpdate').value">
</div>
```

if the condition is 'true', the password field appears. When the submit button is clicked the password field is validated for required.

then the condition is turned to 'false' but the required validation is not removed so the form is not able to get submitted. Kindly help me to sort this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We would need to also take a look at your component to help you out, because the way you're doing it currently, it doesn't work "out of the box". You probably need to manipulate the validation of your form component manually.

Comment: is the any other way to hide and validate? other than validating it manually?

Comment: Anyway [required] is always true, because the *ngIf is checking it

Comment: @Marx-rox i suggest to read through https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I would disable/enable controll - disabled controls are excluded from  validation cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using ReactiveForms, we can add and remove validations based on the status of our "passwordUpdate"

```
<form [formGroup]="contactForm">
  <div>
    <label>Update Password</label>
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="resetPassword" (change)="onCheckboxChange()" />
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="contactForm.get('resetPassword')?.value">
    <label for="last-name">Password: </label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="password">
    Required: {{ contactForm.get('password')?.hasError('required') }}
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    Valid Form : {{ contactForm.valid }}
  </div>
</form>
```

I have added "change" function which triggers a function in .ts file which resets the validation of "password" fields.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  contactForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createContactForm();
  }

  createContactForm() {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      resetPassword: [],
      password: [],
    });
  }

  onCheckboxChange(): void {
    if (this.contactForm.controls['resetPassword'].value) {
      this.contactForm.get('password')?.setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.contactForm.get('password')?.updateValueAndValidity();
    } else {
      this.contactForm.controls['password'].clearValidators();
      this.contactForm.get('password')?.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a mock project of the same on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-if4qq9). please check it for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the FormControl 'password' when the 'password Update' is false so that it is not involved in the validation of the form

you can add the below code in ngOnInit()

```
this.form.get('passwordUpdate').valuechange()
.subscrip(res => {
   if(res===true){
     this.form.get('password').enable();
   } else{
     this.form.get('password').disable();
   }
});
```